# select a specific columns in R nested list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-cleaning

suppose i have a list of data frames, just like this:

```
M1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
M2 <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
M3 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))

mlist <- list(M1, M2, M3)
```

and now i want to select X1 columns from all of dataframes, I tried :

```
M.X1 <- mlist$X1
```

but failed with NULL:

```
> mlist$X1
NULL
```

I don't want to use `for` to extract each data frames' `X1`, is there some better way to do this ? And what if extract columns `X3` ? (which means some columns may not exists in other row)

Comment: `lapply(mlist, '[', 'X1)` and `lapply(mlist, '[[', 'X3')`

Comment: a quote is missing: `...'X1')` but it rocks.

Comment: yes, that's work ! why not add it to answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you can use `lapply` as below:

```
lapply(mlist, function(x) x$X2)
```

The 2nd parameter you define a function right inside to pass to each member of `mlist`.